# ORACLE Golden Gate Classic Installation location relative to Source DB

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

From reading the docs, which are not to the point imho, when wanting to extract from a Source Oracle DB:

- do you need to install OGG Classic on the same Server of the Source Oracle DB always for the *Extract*?
- or, can we move with a script the archived log files to another machine?
- or can the extract work out that the Oracle Source DB is on another server via tnsnames, ldap, oranames, etc?

That is not clear to me from the docs.

Looking at this from licensing cost issues on big db server. Sure, we can shareplex to another machine.

Picture provided:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three scenarios are supported.  Migrating log files from one machine to another is referred to as *Downstream Capture* and using GoldenGate on one machine to capture from the DBMS over the network is referred to as *Remote Capture*.

In addition, with Oracle GoldenGate 19.1 for Oracle, you can capture across operating systems. This means you can run GoldenGate on a Linux machine to capture data from your AIX DBMS environment.